# Is there a way to create a scale that will only consider the absolute value of the domain values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create a scale that will return a valid radius value and I'm trying to handle negative values.  I always want circles to be drawn with a radius of 2px to 40px.  But there's two ways I want to handle negative.

Sometimes I want the min value (even if it's negative) to map to 2px. Imagine a radius that indicates revenue where sometimes it's negative and sometimes it's positive.  I'm acheiving this like so:

```
var rScale = scale.linear.range([2, 40]).domain([minValue, maxValue]);
```

Other times I want 0 to always be the minimum and the domain values to always be considered as their absolute value.  Imagine Richter scape value or anything that oscilates.

```
var rScale = scale.linear.range([2, 40]).domain([0, maxAbsoluteValue]);
```

However, everytime I want a scaled value, I have to take it's absolute value.

```
rScale(Math.abs(dataValue));
```

**Is there a way to create a scale that ALWAYS considers the absolute value of the domain values?  Is there a way to extend the linear scale to do this?**

I don't want to just change the dataValues to be their absolute values as I'll need to keep the raw (negative) value around so I can style the negative circles differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be an elegant, D3-specific solution.

One option is to keep doing what you're doing, e.g.

```
.attr("r", function(d){return rScale(Math.abs(d))})
```

If you only have to do that in one place, and it does what you want, that's not so bad.

If you want something more reusable, you can always wrap the scale:

```
function absRScale(d){return rScale(Math.abs(d))});
// and later...
.attr("r", absRScale)
```

If you modify `rScale` after you've set it up (not a good idea, if you can help it, unless you're doing transitions), then `absRScale` will reflect that. The only catch is that you can't use scale operators (domain, range, etc) on `absRScale`.